# Как в php правильно работать со знаковыми числами?

Tags: php

Следующий код, под Windows выдаст `-1820302793 и 1227` (так бы и хотелось), т.к. под любым Windows и под nix 32-битным - всегда 32-битное знаковое, а под nix х64 получаем знаковое 64 битное `2474664503 и -4294966069`:

```
  $b1=0x93;
  $b2=0x80;
  $b3=0x62;
  $b4=0x37;
  $a=($b1<<24)|($b2<<16)|($b3<<8)|$b4; //всегда из 4 считанных байт
  echo 'a: '.$a.'<br \>';
  $k='-1820301572'; //всегда строка!
  $a=$a ^ intval($k);
  echo 'result: '.$a.'<br \>';
```

Как сделать, чтобы вычисления не зависили от разрядности системы? Хотелось бы работать с 32 бита со знаком везде. Можно проверять `PHP_INT_SIZE`, но как его заставить видеть как 32 битное знаковое?

Comment: Расскажите подробнее об операции, которую вы пытаетесь осуществить. Бинарное представление у этих чисел абсолютно одинаковое, и, если вам надо работать с ними на бинарном уровне, то вы не должны заметить разницы.

Comment: Конечно одинаковое, в том то и беда. Продолжил код, может понятнее станет.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл в сети такое решение:

```
function Int64ToInt32($int64){
  $int32=$int64;
  if($int64<0){
    $int32 &= 0x00000000ffffffff;
  }elseif ($int64>0){
    $int32 |= 0xffffffff00000000;
  }
  return $int32;
}
```

Вроде работает, если кто может предложить элегантнее, или поправить данное, буду рад.